# Date pattern regex doesn't match the records in PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, regex

I am working with a dataset in PostgreSQL which is quick messy. I have written a few regex operations to find date patterns in the records of a table. Since I don't have a generalized REGEX defined for finding any kind of date pattern!, so, I have created a few using some examples found in the database such as:

```
9/18/2010 6:17:00 AM
 05/21/2014
Date 2008-02-13 
7/18/2016 9:54 PM  
 2000-04-20
Booked:1/16/2011 6:45:00 AM (2008-09-01 12:35:45 )
on January 3, 2008 
on July 3, 2002 
23 Mar 2017
5 Feb 2004  
 January 3, 2008 
January 31, 2001
December 19, 2007  
February 2009
February 30
- Feb 3, 2011 
9 Jun 2010
```

[This REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/HFYRzJ/1) matches a few date formats and is able to find the records in the database!:

```
select count(*) from gallery_image where description ~* '(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)|(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)';
```

But, [this REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/XxhvqZ/1) matches the example, but unable to find a single record in the database, even though they are present in the DB since I have taken all the examples from it.?

```
select count(*) from gallery_image where description ~* '(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})';
```

Could anyone point out the mistake I have made in the second query or REGEX pattern that it works normally but not when used in the PostgreSQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not implement Perl regular expression, it implements [POSIX regular expressions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)  One difference among many is that `\b` represents a backspace character, not a word boundary. You can use `\y` to represent a word boundary, although I don't know if that has the exact same meaning as `\b` has in Perl.

If you want to use Perl regular expressions exactly, you could use the PL/Perl language

Comment: ```\y``` worked! I am able to match the records by switching ```\b``` & ```\y``` in the REGEX expression I prepared.